# Format of server certificate in ServerHello (TLS 1.3)

Tags: ssl-certificate, tls1.3

[RFC 8446, section 4.4.2 "Certificate"](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8446#section-4.4.2) (TLS 1.3) describes CertificateEntry.
  I (server) use X.509 certificate and I should pass it in opaque cert_data<1..2^24-1> structure.
  Which format should I use to pass certificate ?
  For example, I have got the certificate in DER format.  Will it be enough to read the whole DER-file and put all its content data in cert_data structure ?

Comment: It's explained in the paragraph in that section that starts out *If the corresponding certificate type extension...*

Comment: @President James K. Polk, thank you very much!